# why this ElasticSearch query not works?

Tags: elasticsearch

here is a nested query works well:

```
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":{
                    "terms" : {
                      "orderInfo.flightSegment.depCity" : [ "NewYork","London" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "path": "orderInfo.flightSegment"
    }
}
}
```

another nested query which want to do the same thing but has deeper nested structure can not get any result:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : {
                "nested" : {
                  "query" : {
                    "bool" : {
                      "must" : {
                        "terms" : {
                          "orderInfo.flightSegment.depCity" : [ "NewYork","London" ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "path" : "orderInfo.flightSegment"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "path" : "orderInfo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

since there may have some other query parameters, so I use boolQuery.must to combine different parameters.
when "NewYork" and "London" both exists in ES, the second query can get the right answer("NewYork" or "London"),but if there is one item not exists in ES(i.e. "NewYork"),the query returns empty result.
Why the second query can not get results in this situation?